# Same styles returning different outputs for table border

Tags: html, css, border

Please view following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dgqr2nLd/2/

```
#myDiv 
{
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

&

```
 border="1px solid #CCCCCC"
```

are returning different results. I would like the single solid grey border line, the same as the border holding 'This is a div'. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

That's an invalid way of using the border attribute. If you want inline styling you should do

```
style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the table border:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dgqr2nLd/4/)**

Note that you also need to fix your inline CSS on the table to `<table style="border:1px solid #ccc" cellpadding="20px 20px 20px 20px">`

Answer (score 0):

The `border` attribute of a `table` element in HTML is quite distinct from the CSS `border` property. They should not be expected to have the same effect. The attribute value used is invalid; browsers in practice act as if you had specified `border="1"`.

Your CSS rule sets a one-pixel solid grey border. If you want the same for a `table` element, just set the same declaration on it.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"
```

add class ".table" to table tag

add this classes

```
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table td{
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;  
}
```